# How to resolve shift reduce conflicts in my grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, syntax, pascal, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm writing a compiler from (reduced) Pascal into ARM asm. I'm at the second step of the process - after writing lexical analyzer now I'm working on syntax analysis with [java cup](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/).

I have written my grammar, but got 5 S/R conflicts, which are all very similar. Example:

```
   Warning : *** Shift/Reduce conflict found in state #150
between assign_stmt ::= val_expr ASSIGN val_expr (*) 
  and     val_expr ::= val_expr (*) LBRACKET val_expr RBRACKET 
  under symbol LBRACKET
  Resolved in favor of shifting
```

My grammar for this section:

```
assign_stmt ::=
 val_expr ASSIGN val_expr;

val_expr ::=
     NIL | BOOL_CONST | INT_CONST | CHAR_CONST | PTR val_expr %prec MEM | ADD val_expr %prec UADD |
     SUB val_expr %prec USUB | NOT val_expr | val_expr PTR %prec VAL | val_expr MUL val_expr |
     val_expr DIV val_expr | val_expr ADD val_expr | val_expr SUB val_expr | val_expr EQU val_expr |
     val_expr NEQ val_expr | val_expr LTH val_expr | val_expr GTH val_expr | val_expr LEQ val_expr |
     val_expr GEQ val_expr | val_expr AND val_expr | val_expr OR val_expr | IDENTIFIER | 
     val_expr LBRACKET val_expr RBRACKET | val_expr DOT IDENTIFIER | IDENTIFIER LPARENTHESIS params_list RPARENTHESIS |
     LBRACKET type_desc RBRACKET | LPARENTHESIS val_expr RPARENTHESIS
    ;
```

How could I eliminate this conflict?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably tag this question with what parser generator you're using - or at least mention it somewhere in the question.

Comment: I've mentioned java cup, but can't add the tag, because you need 1,5k reputation to add new tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your grammar is ambiguous, and both right- and left-recursive. From my (limited) knowledge about parsers, I know this is impossible to parse by most parser generators.

It's ambiguous because `val_expr ADD val_expr SUB val_expr` can be parsed as:

```
       ADD
      /   \
val_expr  SUB
         /   \
   val_expr  val_expr
```

and

```
        SUB
       /   \
     ADD  val_expr
    /   \
val_expr  val_expr
```

I've never used Java CUP, but here's how I did a similar thing using another parser generator:

```
val_expr ::=
    expr1 (SUB | ADD | <add all your operators here>) val_expr
    | expr1 ;

expr1 ::=
    NIL | BOOL_CONST | INT_CONST | CHAR_CONST | <etc> ;
```

This makes the grammar unambiguous and only right-recursive, which can be handled by all parser generators I know of.

A negative aspect of this grammar is that you don't have any precedence, but Java CUP probably has another way to specify precedence.

**Edit**: Fixed first grammar rule.

Comment: I actually had some other issues with my grammar and as I resolved these, all the conflicts "auto-magically" went away. However, I've also changed (and make it prettier) my grammar according to your post. Thank you, I learned something new!